# Israel trials and tribulations

Tags: israel, joel, jews

I want to ask about two passages from Joel. The first one says that

> never again will I make you an object of scorn to the nations (Joel 2:19)

and

> never again will my people be shamed (Joel 2:27)

How should we understand these two passages in the context of the history of Israel and Jews especially the Second War World where Jews were murdered? It seems like Israel once again was made a scorn to the nations and it was shamed but did God again put a judgment or did we (fallen humanity) decide to do by ourselves this horrible act?

Answer (score 1):

It is essential to realize that the Old Testament is a revelation of the coming of Christ, and a new covenant prepared for all nations. It is not a prophesy for incidence of present day, that is generally refer as the end times. Jesus declared Himself came to fulfill the law, He said;

> 17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. (Matthew 5:17 NIV)

Jesus fulfilled the Abrahamic covenant in which the Lord promise Abraham

> through your offspring all nations on earth will be blessed (Genesis 22:18; 26:4 NIV)

All nations are blessed in the promise in Jesus Christ, as Paul indicated;

> 6 This mystery is that through the gospel the Gentiles are heirs together with Israel, members together of one body, and sharers together in the promise in Christ Jesus. (Ephesians 3:6 NIV)

Adolf Hitler Holocaust of the Jews was a racist act. In his book "Mein Kampf", he expressed his belief in the superiority of the Aryan race but however, the Jews in Germany were in quite an extent controlling the Germany economy. The anti-Semitic views was a convenient excuse to seize their economic power. Therefore it can be imagined, a nationalist dictator will do horrible things to whoever stand before him even though they do no harm to him. It occurred in Germany at the second world war, it will occur anywhere else as long as a dictator stand.

It can be seen holocaust still exist to this day in Africa and Asia. Before Christ Satan may target only on the Israelites. Now the preaching of Gospel spread to the whole world, everyone must be in precaution, as Peter warned;

> 8 Be alert and of sober mind. Your enemy the devil prowls around like a roaring lion looking for someone to devour. (1 Peter 5:8 NIV)

Comment: I agree with your O.T. is a rev' of the coming of Christ, but can you back this up with Bible quotes to reference this?

Comment: @C.Stroud - I try a long story short and hopefully the added quotes can basically answer your request.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the context of the two verses:

> <sup>12</sup>That is why the LORD says,
> “**Turn to me now, while there is time**.
> Give me your hearts.
> Come with fasting, weeping, and mourning.
>
> <sup>13</sup>Don’t tear your clothing in your grief,
> but tear your hearts instead.”
> **Return to the LORD your God**.
> for he is merciful and compassionate,
> slow to get angry and filled with unfailing love.
> He is eager to relent and not punish.
>
> <sup>14</sup>Who knows? **Perhaps he will give you a reprieve,
> sending you a blessing instead of this curse**.
> Perhaps you will be able to offer grain and wine
> to the LORD your God as before.
>
> <sup>15</sup>Blow the ram’s horn in Jerusalem!
> **Announce a time of fasting**;
> call the people together
> for a solemn meeting.
>
> <sup>16</sup>**Gather all the people** —
> the elders, the children, and even the babies.
> Call the bridegroom from his quarters
> and the bride from her private room.
>
> <sup>17</sup>**Let the priests**, who minister in the LORD’s presence,
> **stand and weep between the entry room to the Temple and the altar**.
> Let them pray, “Spare your people, LORD!
> Don’t let your special possession become an object of mockery.
> Don’t let them become a joke for unbelieving foreigners who say,
> ‘Has the God of Israel left them?’”
>
> <sup>18</sup>**Then the LORD will pity his people
> and jealously guard the honor of his land.**
>
> <sup>19</sup>The LORD will reply,
> “Look! I am sending you grain and new wine and olive oil,
> enough to satisfy your needs.
> **You will no longer be an object of mockery
> among the surrounding nations**.
>
> …
>
> <sup>27</sup>**Then you will know that I am among my people Israel**,
> that I am the LORD your God, and there is no other.
> **Never again will my people be disgraced**.
> The LORD’s Promise of His Spirit

Yes, God says that this would never happen again, but he preceded that with what he wanted Israel to do first.
*All* the people, including the civil and religious leaders, needed to truly repent, to ask for God's forgiveness.

But this never happened; the people did not repent; they rejected God's offer.

God of course knew they would.
Consider the larger context wrapped around these verses:

> <sup>1</sup>Sound the alarm in Jerusalem!
> Raise the battle cry on my holy mountain!
> Let everyone tremble in fear
> because **the day of the LORD is upon us**.
>
> <sup>2</sup>It is a day of darkness and gloom,
> a day of thick clouds and deep blackness.
> Suddenly, like dawn spreading across the mountains,
> a great and mighty army appears.
> **Nothing like it has been seen before
> or will ever be seen again**.
>
> <sup>3</sup>Fire burns in front of them,
> and flames follow after them.
> Ahead of them the land lies
> as beautiful as the Garden of Eden.
> Behind them is nothing but desolation;
> not one thing escapes.
>
> <sup>4</sup>They look like horses;
> they charge forward like warhorses.
>
> <sup>5</sup>Look at them as they leap along the mountaintops.
> Listen to the noise they make — like the rumbling of chariots,
> like the roar of fire sweeping across a field of stubble,
> or like a mighty army moving into battle.
>
> <sup>6</sup>**Fear grips all the people;
> every face grows pale with terror**.
>
> <sup>7</sup>The attackers march like warriors
> and scale city walls like soldiers.
> Straight forward they march,
> never breaking rank.
>
> <sup>8</sup>They never jostle each other;
> each moves in exactly the right position.
> They break through defenses
> without missing a step.
>
> <sup>9</sup>They swarm over the city
> and run along its walls.
> They enter all the houses,
> climbing like thieves through the windows.
>
> <sup>10</sup>**The earth quakes** as they advance,
> and **the heavens tremble**.
> **The sun and moon grow dark**,
> and **the stars no longer shine**.
>
> <sup>11</sup>The LORD is at the head of the column.
> He leads them with a shout.
> This is his mighty army,
> and they follow his orders.
> **The day of the LORD is an awesome, terrible thing**.
> Who can possibly survive?
>
> …
>
> <sup>28</sup>“Then, after doing all those things,
> **I will pour out my Spirit upon all people**.
> Your sons and daughters will prophesy.
> Your old men will dream dreams,
> and your young men will see visions.
>
> <sup>29</sup>**In those days I will pour out my Spirit
> even on servants — men and women alike**.
>
> <sup>30</sup>**And I will cause wonders in the heavens and on the earth —
> blood and fire and columns of smoke**.
>
> <sup>31</sup>**The sun will become dark**,
> and **the moon will turn blood red**
> before **that great and terrible day of the LORD** arrives.
>
> <sup>32</sup>But everyone who calls on the name of the LORD
> will be saved,
> for some on Mount Zion in Jerusalem will escape,
> just as the LORD has said.
> These will be among the survivors
> whom the LORD has called.

The first part is a prophecy of the end-times, of the Day of the Lord.
The second part is is a prophecy of the World to Come, of the Kingdom of God that will follow.

These prophecies are repeated by other latter prophets, and again by Jesus in *Matthew 24* and by John in *Revelation*.